# CSS float clearing issue

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am using float and then clearing both. but still i have getting some error in the layout. can some one point out what the problem is ?

http://uniquedl.com/3closets/about.html

i want Sneak-peek control div and sneak peek products div to be next to each other. i am using this code to make it next to each other

```
.grid {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

But sneek-control is taking a lot of margin to the left and not sitting below the above div block

[image]

i want the layout to look like this

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit by stating what you are exactly trying to do? Source code (excerpts) would also help.

Comment: @Aron sure will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a height on your .intro-image to 384px same size as image it should work.

```
.introduction .intro-image {
    width: 288px;
    height: 384px;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. there is a small gap under the .introduction and .showcase  is it bcos of the float ?

Comment: I changed the answer..see above. You can take the previous 390px off. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

.sneak-peek {

```
clear: both;
float: left;
height: 288px;
text-align: left;
```

}

should do it.

You also have some problems there... check IE 7 after you finish. Probably they'll clear out by themselves.